# Error related to 'list' object with no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, attributeerror, tfidfvectorizer

I'm doing multiple clustering projects. In my current clustering project, I get an error related to my tfidf_vectorizer code.

**Here are the documents I've imported:**

```
description_1 = open('description1.txt', 
encoding="utf8").read().lower().split('\n')
description_2 = open('description2.txt', 
encoding="utf8").read().lower().split('\n')
description_3 = open('description3.txt', 
encoding="utf8").read().lower().split('\n')
description_4 = open('description4.txt', 
encoding="utf8").read().lower().split('\n')
description_5 = open('description5.txt', 
encoding="utf8").read().lower().split('\n')
description_6 = open('description6.txt', 
encoding="utf8").read().lower().split('\n')
description_7 = open('description7.txt', 
encoding="utf8").read().lower().split('\n')
```

**I've then combined the documents:**

```
descriptions_on = (description_1, description_2, description_3, 
description_4, description_5, description_6, description_7)

descriptions = []

for i in range(len(descriptions_on)):
    item = descriptions_on[i]
    descriptions.append(item)
```

**The problem arises somewhere in theses lines of code**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from spacy.lang.fr.stop_words import STOP_WORDS as fr_stop
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS as en_stop
#from warnings import filterwarnings
#filterwarnings('ignore')

final_stopwords_list = list(fr_stop) + list(en_stop)

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.90, max_features=200000,
                             min_df=0.10, stop_words=final_stopwords_list,
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, 
ngram_range=(1,3))


%time tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(descriptions)
```

*The tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem is related to a function "tokenize_and_stem" that had been created and not included in the list of codes for this question as it would be impertinent.*

**Here is the error message I get from the code above:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<timed exec> in <module>

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in 
fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1611         """
   1612         self._check_params()
->     1613         X = super(TfidfVectorizer, 
self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
   1614         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   1615         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

 D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in 
fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1029 
   1030         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
 ->1031                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1032 
   1033         if self.binary:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in 
_count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    941         for doc in raw_documents:
    942             feature_counter = {}
--> 943             for feature in analyze(doc):
    944                 try:
    945                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in 
<lambda>(doc)
    327                                                tokenize)
    328             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
--> 329                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), 
stop_words)
    330 
    331         else:

 D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in 
<lambda>(x)
    255 
    256         if self.lowercase:
--> 257             return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
    258         else:
    259             return strip_accents

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Obviously, I'm hoping that the code can run without any errors. I've tried multiple things to try to solve this problem. I even read 6-7 posts that had the same question on stack, yet every one of them was different than mine in some way...

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thank you!*

**EDIT:**

```
print(descriptions)
```

**RESULT:**

[['\ufefffounded in montreal in 1991. dex is a true pioneer in affordable luxury.', 'guest post by sashana sanderson, 2nd year journalism student at caribbean institute of media & communications (carimac), located on the university of the west indies...', 'diamentis offers a simple and reliable solution in personalised medicine, with a more precise and diamentis is developing a first diagnostic tool in mental health care that will allow clinicians a more...', 'didacte empowers training vendors. create online courses on your cloud based portal within minutes.', 'di-o-matic: discover the technologies behind your favorite cg characters', 'proship facilite le recrutement des talents et la préparation du spectacle qui éblouira vos invités, tout en assurant la gestion de la totalité des problèmes administratifs et contractuels.', 'dk-spec participe au congrès de montréal sur le bois, du 20 au 22 mars, au fairmont le reine élisabeth. venez nous rencontrer!', 'do networks limited is aiming at being one-stop service suppliers to customers for enterprise with rich expertise in optical communication line, do networks limited whole team is committed to being...', "douglas consultants inc. douglas consultants est une firme d'ingénieurs-conseils fondée en 1999 spécialisée en structures de bâtiments.", 'cooper currently sits on the board of directors of dream, dream office reit, dream global reit, dream industrial reit and e-l financial corporation limited. ms. p. jane gavan is the president, asset management of dream and has more than 30 years of experience in the real estate industry.', "dromadaire géo-innovations est une firme spécialisée en géomatique. au service de l'environnement, l'entreprise utilise la géo-localisation pour faire l ...", "dubo électrique ltée est l'expert-conseil spécialiste des produits électriques, de l'éclairage, d'automatisation et de contrôle au québec, c'est pourquoi traiter avec dubo électrique ltée comporte...", 'dundee sustainable technologies (dst) is engaged in the development and commercialization of environment-friendly technologies for the treatment of materials in

Comment: can you try printing `descriptions` and show us the sample?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal  absolutely, I've edited the post... the result is part of the print(description). The full output would be too long to post.

Comment: looks like this is list of list not list of text and tfidf is expecting list of texts

Comment: I basically have 7 documents, as posted at the beginning of the post, each have 100 lines of text.

Comment: and will it be okay if you convert the lines to paragraph for that document?

Comment: or want just lines by lines only?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal I just added the [0] and ran the code. No error is showing up (which is great! ). Does that however take into account only the first paragraph of "descriptions_on"?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal Just line by line, as I am doing clusters that need to basically take into account every line individually to try to find similarities between them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197692/discussion-between-upasana-mittal-and-ontharise).

Answer (score 0):

Your documents are `list`s of lines, not strings.

Hence they don't have the proper format for the tokenizer.